# Is there a -onym term for a genericised trademarks?

Tags: single-word-requests

In UK English we use [genericised trademarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks) in everyday speech, e.g.:

> Could you *hoover* the carpet, please?
>
> I've *googled* him
>
> Was that your car they just announced on the *tannoy*?

I seem to recall there being a fancy, academic word for this "type" of word e.g. a something-onym.

Is there?

Comment: @killingtime  ~~~That is not a duplicate question in the slightest. This most definitely has not been answered.~~~ Actually, one of the lower down answers held the answer: Generonym!

Comment: Why is it essential that the term end in *-onym*?

Comment: I would always capitalise Hoover, Google, Tannoy, and although I say (and write) 'photocopy' I would write Xerox if I became American, I suppose. I might blow my nose on a Kleenex, and I write little notes on capitalised and hyphenated Post-Its. When I was a schoolchild in the 1950s and 1960s, we were not allowed to write with Biros.

Comment: @jws29 because I remember it ending with that :)